# Using dplyr's rename() including variable names not in data set

Tags: r, plyr, dplyr

I am trying to transition some plyr code to dplyr, and getting stuck with the new functionality of rename() in dplyr. I'd like to be able to reuse a single rename() expression for a set of datasets with overlapping but not identical original names. For example,

```
sample1 <- data.frame(A=1:10, B=letters[1:10])

sample2 <- data.frame(B=11:20, C=letters[11:20])
```

And then,

```
 rename(sample1, var1 = A, var2 = B, var3 = C)
```

I would like the result to be that variable A is renamed var1, and B is renamed var2, not adding a var3 in this case. Instead, I get

Error: Unknown variables: C.

In contrast, the plyr syntax would let me use

```
rename(sample1, c("A" = "var1", "B" = "var2", "C" = "var3"))
rename(sample2, c("A" = "var1", "B" = "var2", "C" = "var3"))
```

and not throw an error. Is there a way to get the same result in dplyr without getting the Unknown variables error?

Comment: You could reference the rename function specifically from plyr: `plyr::rename(sample1, c("A" = "var1", "B" = "var2", "C" = "var3"))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Completely ignoring your actual request on how to do this with dplyr, I would like suggest a different approach using a lookup table:

```
sample1 <- data.frame(A=1:10, B=letters[1:10])
sample2 <- data.frame(B=11:20, C=letters[11:20])

rename_map <- c("A"="var1",
                "B"="var2",
                "C"="var3")

names(sample1) <- rename_map[names(sample1)]
str(sample1)

names(sample2) <- rename_map[names(sample2)]
str(sample2)
```

Fundamentally the algorithm is simple:

1. Build a lookup table of current variable names to desired names
2. Using the names() function, do a lookup into the map with the mapping indexes and assign those mapped variables to the appropriate columns.

EDIT: As per Hadley's suggestion, I used a named vector instead of a list, makes life much easier. I always forget about named vectors :(

Comment: You could make this rather simpler by using a named character vector rather than a named list

Comment: If you only want to name a subset of columns, this will set all other existing column names to NA.

Answer (score 1):

```
    #no need to use rename 

    oldnames<-unique(c(names(sample1),names(sample2)))
    newnames<-c("var1","var2","var3")
    name_df<-data.frame(oldnames,newnames)
    mydata<-list(sample1,sample2) # combined two datasets as a list
#one liner
    finaldata <- lapply(mydata, function(i) {colnames(i)<-name_df[name_df[,1] %in%  colnames(i),2]
return(i)})
> finaldata
[[1]]
   var1 var2
1     1    a
2     2    b
3     3    c
4     4    d
5     5    e
6     6    f
7     7    g
8     8    h
9     9    i
10   10    j

[[2]]
   var2 var3
1    11    k
2    12    l
3    13    m
4    14    n
5    15    o
6    16    p
7    17    q
8    18    r
9    19    s
10   20    t
```

Answer (score 1):

I’ve used [@earino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45403/earino)’s answer before
myself, but discovered that it can be unsafe. If column names of the data
frame are missing in the (names of the) named vector, those column names are silently replaced with `NA` and that is certainly not what you want.

```r
d1 <- data.frame(A = 1:10, B = letters[1:10], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

rename_vec <- c("B" = "var2", "C" = "var3")

names(d1) <- rename_vec[names(d1)]
str(d1)
#> 'data.frame':    10 obs. of  2 variables:
#>  $ NA  : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#>  $ var2: chr  "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
```

The same can happen, if you run `names(d1) <- rename_vec[names(d1)]`
twice by accident, because when you run it the second time, none of the
`colnames(d1)` are in `names(rename_vec)`.

```r
names(d1) <- rename_vec[names(d1)]
str(d1)
#> 'data.frame':    10 obs. of  2 variables:
#>  $ NA: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#>  $ NA: chr  "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
```

We just need to select those columns that are in the data frame *and* in the rename vector.

```r
d2 <- data.frame(B1 = 1:10, B = letters[1:10], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

sel <- is.element(colnames(d2), names(rename_vec))
names(d2)[sel] <- rename_vec[names(d2)][sel]
str(d2)
#> 'data.frame':    10 obs. of  2 variables:
#>  $ B1  : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#>  $ var2: chr  "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
```

UPDATE: I initially had a solution here that involved string replacement, which turned out to be unsafe as well, because it allowed for partial matching. This one is better, I think.

Comment: You could also stick with original solution but for safety add something like the following above: `stopifnot(all(names(sample1) %in% names(rename_vec )))`

Comment: @snoram I found a better solution than my original one, I think, which essentially is just a small adjustment to earino's.

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`, we can use a named vector with old names as values and new names as names, then unquote only the values in `name_vec` that matches names in your dataset. `rename` supports unquoting characters, so there is no need to convert them to `sym` beforehand:

```
library(dplyr)

name_vec <- c(var1 = "A", var2 = "B", var3 = "C")

sample1 %>%
  rename(!!name_vec[name_vec %in% names(.)])

sample2 %>%
  rename(!!name_vec[name_vec %in% names(.)])
```

Also, with `setNames`:

```
name_vec <- c(A = "var1", B = "var2", C = "var3")

sample1 %>%
  setNames(name_vec[names(.)])

sample2 %>%
  setNames(name_vec[names(.)])
```

**Output:**

```
   var1 var2
1     1    a
2     2    b
3     3    c
4     4    d
5     5    e
6     6    f
7     7    g
8     8    h
9     9    i
10   10    j

   var2 var3
1    11    k
2    12    l
3    13    m
4    14    n
5    15    o
6    16    p
7    17    q
8    18    r
9    19    s
10   20    t
```